# How to open local files by button click and upload multiple files and display like gmail feature to delete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I tried implementing Multiple file document by clicking the button like gmail with progress bar and cancel upload in ASP.NET webapp using c#.net

So I have implemented as per below links
1.http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-and-Upload-Multiple-Files-Gmail-Style-using-JQuery-and-ASP.Net.aspx
2.http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/376_Upload_Multiple_Files_in_ASPNet_Using_jQuery_in_GMAIL_style.aspx
my requirement is exatly like that but after implementing as above explained I am not getting the browser button 
If any one has an idea on it please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged your question with the Telerik tag, so here are two ideas based on their controls:

- **RadAsyncUpload** lets you upload multiple files and has progress bars for each: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/multiplefileselection/defaultcs.aspx. Review the rest of the demos to see all its features.
- **RadFileExplorer** lets your end users manage files on the server, including upload and delete features: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for your reply using telerik but i need  upload files with out file control i need to display uploaded files in div by clicking attach button like Gmail.if it is available your most wecome.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. The AsyncUpload provides a list with the files OOB, FileExplorer gives you three upload inputs by default in its Upload dialog. I am not sure what "without file control" should mean. To upload files, you need an <input type="file">. When you upload the files, you can loop through the collection and create child elements for your div.